# fstream not reading all integers

Tags: c++, data-structures, fstream, doubly-linked-list

I created a doubly linked list class and driver.  I'm supposed to read in integers to the list from a text file but it's **not reading the last number (37)** and I'm not sure why.  I'm almost positive it's not an issue with the initializeItem() or insertItem() functions so I'm not listing those but I can if needed.

Here's the text file:

> 9 10 3 84 19 63 1 45 100 37

Here's the code I have to read it in:

```
DoublyLinkedList list;
ItemType item;
int input;
std::fstream fs;

fs.open(argv[1], fstream::in);
if (fs.is_open())
{
    fs >> input;
    while (!fs.eof())
    {
        item.initialize(input);
        list.insertItem(item);
        fs >> input;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "File could not be opened."
         << " Try again"
         << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I print out the list (sorted) I get this:

> 1 3 9 10 19 45 63 84 100

Comment: I changed you code a little bit to remove initialize and insertItem so that I can run. It works as expected. So it might be your initializeItem() or insertItem() function which caused your problem. Also I agree with @templatetypedef that while (fs >> input) would be better.

Answer (score 2):

The `.eof()` function on a stream doesn't trigger if an operation failed to complete due to reading the end of a file. Rather, it reports whether, in the course of any operation, it encountered the end of a stream. It's entirely possible that `.eof()` returns true even if the last operation succeeded. In fact, the general wisdom is that it is almost always wrong to test for `.eof()` if you're doing stream reads.

Here's a better way to read from the stream:

```
while (fs >> input) {
    ... do something with fs ...
}
```

This code will repeatedly pull values out of the stream until an operation fails to complete successfully (as determined by `.fail()`, not `.eof()`). This general pattern is probably the best way to read numbers from a stream if you know that they're whitespace-delimited.